# How do i check if I am using jQuery-file-upload plugin version 9.22.1 or newer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I need to check the version of jQuery-file-upload plugin being used on my web page. 
I believe that jQuery-file-upload plugin by blueimp is embedded in jQuery-ui widget. If this is true, then how do we check if jQuery-file-upload version being used is 9.22.1 or newer? I am trying to see if my webpage is vulnerable to CVE-2018-9206

Answer (score 0):

use this for check version

```
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

or

```
console.log(jQuery().jquery);
```

Comment: This gives me version of jQeury being used. Awesome. Now how do I verify the version of jQeury-file-upload plugin? Because remediation of CVE-2018-9206 suggests to update the plugin to 9.22.1 or newer, not the jQeury.